# Can't get Dart asset_pack package example code to run correctly

Tags: dart

So I am trying to make a game in Dart and I decided to check out this [asset_pack package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/asset_pack). I tried to test the example code (below) but `asset.imported` prints `null`..why is this?

I did create /web/test/foo.txt in my project folder and put a little bit of text in it but still I get `null` printed.

```dart
main() {
  // Construct a new AssetManager.
  AssetManager assets = new AssetManager();
  // Register the 'test' pack. No url is needed so the empty string suffices.
  AssetPack testPack = assets.registerPack('test', '');
  // Register asset 'foo' and load it's contents from 'foo.txt'.
  // The asset type is 'text' and there are no arguments for the loader
  // or importer.
  Future<Asset> futureAsset = testPack.loadAndRegisterAsset('foo', 'foo.txt',
                                                            'text', {}, {})
  futureAsset.then((asset) {
    // Print the contents of foo.txt.
    print(asset.imported);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think your file has to be in the web/ folder or you have to load 'test/foo.txt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your file has to be in the `web/` folder or you have to load `test/foo.txt`. If you run the example you should see an error that the file was not found in the developer console. This code seems to work:

```
  Future<Asset> futureAsset = testPack.loadAndRegisterAsset('foo', 'text', 
                                                            'test/foo.txt', {}, {})
```

Comment: I'll have to check later but IIRC I tried something like that but to no avail.

Comment: I also noticed that the order of the arguments is wrong. I updated my answer! I will send a pull request to asset_pack to fix the wrong example.

Comment: I see... errors in the example eh? How unfortunate.  There's also the minor error that the load and register function call has no semicolon after it.

Comment: Yes, with the path as "test/foo.txt" and the arguments in the right order, it works! Thanks :)